# Unable to clone a GIT repository using Ant Target

Tags: git, github, ant

I'm trying to write an Ant target to clone a git repository. Following is the Ant target. Here the ORGANIZATION is the name of the company, GROUP is the group name, and REPOSITORY is the name of the repository.

```
<target name ="clone">
     <sshexec host="github.ORGANIZATION.com"
        username="git"
        keyfile="${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa"
        passphrase="pujain"
        trust="true"
        command="git clone git@github.ORGANIZATION.com:GROUP/REPOSITORY.git"/>
  </target>
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> [sshexec]   You appear to be using ssh to clone a git:// URL.
>   [sshexec]   Make sure your core.gitProxy config option and the
>   [sshexec]   GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable are NOT set.

I'm able to execute the same command from cmd.

Comment: So you're trying to clone this Git repo on a remote machine?

Comment: Yes on a remote machine.

Comment: You still need an exec task, not an ssh task. See my answer below.

Comment: Your remote machine is actually named `github.ORGANIZATION.com`?

Comment: @CAustin Nope. I mean I will be running this script from the remote machine itself. I will put this script on all of our VM's and will run the scrips from there only. 

Right now, to test I'm running this script from my location machine.

Comment: @VonC You mean just write the git repo url in the exec task command? No password, key? Appreciate if you could give an example.

Comment: @PuneetJain I mean exec the git clone ssh url command, not ssh to execute git clone. As I mention in the answer, connect to a remote server to execute git clone does not make sense.

Comment: @PuneetJain I have edited my answer to illustrate the exec.

Comment: If you are running this script from the same machine that you want Git to run on, then this is a *local* command and you need to use `exec`, not`sshexec`. Also, you don't need to use a password with git's SSH access and in most cases you don't need to tell git where your key file is. VonC's answer should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper SSH URL would be (for a private self-hosted GitLab server):

```
git@github.ORGANIZATION.com:GROUPNAME/REPOSITORY.git
                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

There should be a ':', and a group or personal account, *before* the repo name.

What your [`sshexec taks`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) is trying to do is:

- connect to host "`git@github.ORGANIZATION.com:REPOSITORY.git`" (which does not make sense)
- once connected to a remote server, execute `git clone`.

If your script needs to clone a GitLab repo, all you need is an [exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html), not an SSH exec task.

```
<exec executable="git" dir="D:\" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="clone git@github.ORGANIZATION.com:REPOSITORY.git dest" />
</exec>
```

But that won't work with a passphrase-protected private key (unless [it loaded in ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/) first).
You would be better off using [read-only deploy key](https://blog.github.com/2015-06-16-read-only-deploy-keys/) made just for that usage, without passphrase.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Questions -
1.) Should I run git pull also like this? 
2.) If I want to do it through http instead of ssh. Should I clone the http url in the same way?

Comment: Yes, and yes. The general idea is: don't use sshexec to execute something on the remote server. Use exec to execute something locally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this belong in the host name? `:REPOSITORY.git`?

Perhaps this will work?

`<target name ="clone">
     <sshexec host="github.ORGANIZATION.com"
        username="user"
        password="pass"
        passphrase="para"
        trust="true"
        command="git clone git@github.ORGANIZATION.com:REPOSITORY.git  D:/dest"
     />
  </target>`

And just to clear things up, so, you want to connect to ssh server **github.ORGANIZATION.com** as user **user** and then run command `git clone whatever D:/dest` on that server. Is that right?

Comment: Correct. Even this didn't work. Same exception. 

C:\Users\pjai12\Desktop\build.xml:26: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: git@github.ORGANIZATION.com

Comment: My bad, user didn't belong in the host field

Comment: @VonC Actually I do have a group name in the repo URL. Here is the updated target:

  <target name ="clone">
     <sshexec host="github.ORGANIZATION.com"
        username="my email"
        password="my password"
        passphrase="my paraphrase"
        trust="true"
        command="git clone github.ORGANIZATION.com:GROUP/REPOSITORY.git  C:/test"
     />
  </target>

But, now I'm getting "Auth fail" exception. I confirm my username and password is correct.

Comment: @eftshift0 Done

Comment: @PuneetJain I meant: the user has to be `git`. No password. Hopefully, no passphrase (try first with a passphrase-less private SSH key)

Comment: Okay. The auth went successful but now I'm getting a different exception. I've updated my question.